# Can Cartesian product of two lists return all the combinations except the combinations involving two same elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartesian-product

For Example

`nested = [a,b,c]`

Cartesian product of the above list by itself will generate the following pairs

`[(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c),(b,b),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c)]`

I want to find a way to generate the following

`[(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b)]`

I tried the following

`[(x,y) for x in nested for y in nested if x != y]`

The above code fails for the following test case

```
nested_testcase1 = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]]
```

Now the above line of code will give out the following result

`[([1,2],[2,3]),([2,3],[1,2]),([1,2],[2,3]),([2,3],[1,2])]`

But what I what is the following

`[([1,2],[2,3]),([2,3],[1,2]),([1,2],[2,3]),([2,3],[1,2]),([1,2],[1,2]),([1,2],[1,2])]`

The last two combinations coming by pairing the first and last element.

Anyone has got any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it with itertools permutations

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations(['a','b','c'], r=2))
```

The output is as you like

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
```

This works also for your case:

```
list(itertools.permutations([[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]], 2))
```

The output is

```
[([1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [2, 3])]
```

For reference look here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 1):

One simple change: use the object reference, rather than the value:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in nested for y in nested if id(x) is not id(y)]
[([1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [2, 3])]
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using indices but this is far more elegant.

Comment: You could also use `x is not y` instead of comparing `id(x)` and `id(y)`

Comment: @Heike: Thanks for fixing my brain freeze.  `is not` is superior for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index instead of checking the value, like:

```
[(x, y) for i, x in enumerate(data) for j, y in enumerate(data) if i != j]
```

For example:

```
>>> [(x, y) for i, x in enumerate(data) for j, y in enumerate(data) if i != j]
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
>>> data = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]]
>>> [(x, y) for i, x in enumerate(data) for j, y in enumerate(data) if i != j]
[([1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [2, 3])]
```